# How to group a dictionary with dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to group the dictionary below by the value of group, the 
output would like to have such a value.

Current Structure:

```
{'sfp_dnscommonsrv': {'object': 
<modules.sfp_dnscommonsrv.sfp_dnscommonsrv object at 0x7f448bd6ac50>, 
'name': 'DNS Common SRV', 'cats': ['Footprint', 'Investigate', 
'Passive'], 'group': 'DNS', 'labels': ['']}, sfp__stor_db': {'object': 
<modules.sfp__stor_db.sfp__stor_db object at 0x7f448bd6acc0>, 'name': 
'Storage', 'cats': [''], 'group': 'DNS', 'labels': ['']}}
```

Success:

```
{'DNS': [{value where group is DNS}, {value where group is DNS}], 
'DNS2': [{value where group is DNS2}]},
```

Simple version:

Data:

```
{'wood': {'color': 'red', 'group': 'old'}, 'stone': {'color': 'gray', 'group': 'old'}, 'glass': {'color': 'white', 'group': 'new'}}
```

Result:

```
{'old': [{'color': 'red', 'material': 'wood'},{'color': 'gray', 'material': 'stone'}], 'new': [{'color': 'white', 'material': 'glass'}]}
```

Comment: You need to make a [mre].

Comment: @wjandrea  Added

Comment: There are still a bunch of names undefined: `my_dict` and `modules`, also `groupby` but I assume it's from `itertools`. And I think you forgot the quotes on `group` and `material`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to achieve this in a one-liner.

But first there are a few things to clarify:

- In your simple version you have a key `group` that is not defined. I'm just assuming this is a string: `'group'`.
- The key `'material'` in your desired output is not present in your input data, so I'll just add this key during the construction of the result dict, using the values form the input data as values for this new key.
- Simply grouping by a key will not remove this key-value pair from the dict automatically, so after grouping you will still have your 'group' keys in your dicts.

So this is how your `groupby` might look:

```py
from itertools import groupby

init_data = {'wood': {'color': 'red', group: 'old'}, 'stone': {'color': 'gray', group: 'old'}, 'glass': {'color': 'white', group: 'new'}}

# this is in a one-liner, however I added some newlines for readability :)
grouped_data = {
    k: list(
        {
            _k: _v for d in (
                {'material': av[0]},  # this is just to add the 'material' key
                av[1]
            ) for _k,_v in d.items()
        } for av in v
        ) for k, v in groupby(
            init_data.items(),
            lambda x: x[1]['group']
        )
    }
grouped_data

Out[7]: {'new': [{'color': 'white', 'group': 'new', 'material': 'glass'}],
 'old': [{'color': 'gray', 'group': 'old', 'material': 'stone'},
  {'color': 'red', 'group': 'old', 'material': 'wood'}]}
```

Comment: Could you look at my other question? It is connected with lists, and it seems to me that you can answer it. Thank you in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650261/how-to-find-duplicate-list-values?noredirect=1#comment101751074_57650261

Comment: @question_mark_77 I did. Have a look at my answer (I hope I understood you correctly): https://stackoverflow.com/a/57650730/1622937