# How to find duplicate list values?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have an unusual task. Data:

```
[(1566767777.0, 'Aaron Paul', 'dorety1', 'sfp_names', 'HUMAN_NAME', 100, 100, 0, '8ff7', '08f3', 'Human Name', 'ENTITY', '19fd', 0, 0),
 (1566767863.0, 'Aaron Paul', "{'username': 'aaronpaul', 'last_name': 'Paul', 'friends_count': 509, 'is_group': False, 'is_active': True, 'trust_request': None, 'phone': None, 'profile_picture_url': 'http, 'is_blocked': False, 'id': '1690', 'identity': None, 'date_joined': '2015-05-22T18:58:12', 'about': ' ', 'display_name': 'Aaron Paul', 'first_name': 'Aaron', 'friend_status': None, 'email': None}", 'sfp_names', 'HUMAN_NAME', 100, 100, 0, '7049', 'a458', 'Human Name', 'ENTITY', '19fd', 0, 0),
 (1566, 'Aaron Paul', 'Possible full name: Aaron Paul', 'sfp_names', 'HUMAN_NAME', 100, 100, 0, '6685', '235f', 'Human Name', 'ENTITY', '19fd', 0, 0),
 (1566767503.0, 'Antoine Griezmann', 'dorety', 'sfp_names', 'HUMAN_NAME', 100, 100, 0, '16ab', '08f3', 'Human Name', 'ENTITY', '19fd', 0, 0),
 (1566767108.0, 'Boris Johnson', 'dorety', 'sfp_names', 'HUMAN_NAME', 100, 100, 0, '7931', '08f3', 'Human Name', 'ENTITY', '19fd', 0, 0)]
```

I need to get values ​​from the turples in which [1] is duplicated and [3] is not duplicated. That is, in the data above, we always have the same [3] (sfp_names), and in several results of [1](Aaron Paul), that is, from this list we should only get (`1566767777.0, 'Aaron Paul', 'dorety1' , 'sfp_names', 'HUMAN_NAME', 100, 100, 0, '8ff7', '08f3', 'Human Name', 'ENTITY', '19fd', 0, 0)` and two others that have the name Aaron Paul. Since we generally have no difference in how many lists it occurs. We need to get the same value from these three lists `[['Aaron Paul', 'sfp_names']]`. But if we had a third turple with the module name sfp_names_2, then we need to get two values ​​already, since the modules are different. `[['Aaron Paul', 'sfp_names'], ['Aaron Paul', 'sfp_names_2']]`.

Regarding what I did myself, nothing came to my mind on this part; I just have ways to find duplicates inside the list.

I understand what I described is very difficult to understand, so I gave some simple examples of how it should work below

Simple version

Data:

```
[(0, 'Boby', 'beekeeper'), (1, 'Boby', 'beekeeper'), (2, 'Boby', 'beekeeper'), (3, 'Boby', 'gardener')]
```

Result:

```
['Boby', 'beekeeper']
```

or

Data:

```
[(0, 'Boby', 'beekeeper'), (1, 'Boby', 'beekeeper'), (2, 'Boby', 'beekeeper'), (3, 'Boby', 'gardener'), (4, 'Boby', 'gardener'), (5, 'Jack', 'gardener')]
```

Result:

```
[['Boby', 'beekeeper'], ['Boby', 'gardener']]
```

Comment: Please give some simpler example data and the expected output. See [ask] and [mcve] for more tips. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: I read it like 5 Times and still  have no idea what you mean or what you want to achieve, please give an example of the wanted output or try to make it your Problem easier to understand

Comment: @basilisk Added

Comment: @question_mark_77 could you work out your problem?

Comment: @jojo Sorry for delay. Yes, I managed to solve this problem, but now I need to make a little complication, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if I understand you correctly:

You would like to get all elements (tuples) of a list that have a collection of entries occurring multiple times in your list?!

A compact implementation can be realized if you combine `itertools.groupby` with the `operator.itemgetter`. **This actually results in a one-liner expression**:

```py
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

# how often must the pattern appear (redundancy)
# what indices determine the pattern (target_slots)
redundancy, target_slots = 2, (1, 2)

eg_data_2 =  [(0, 'Boby', 'beekeeper'), (1, 'Boby', 'beekeeper'), (2, 'Boby','beekeeper'), (3, 'Boby', 'gardener'), (4, 'Boby', 'gardener'), (5, 'Jack', 'gardener')]

targets = [k for k, v in groupby(eg_data_2, itemgetter(*target_slots)) if sum(1 for _ in v)>=redundancy]

targets
Out[6]: [('Boby', 'beekeeper'), ('Boby', 'gardener')]
```

For your original data (`orig_data` below) you would get:

```py
target_slots = [1,3]
targets = [k for k, v in groupby(orig_data, itemgetter(*target_slots)) if sum(1 for _ in v)>=redundancy]

In [9]: targets                                                           
Out[9]: [('Aaron Paul', 'sfp_names')]
```

---

*As alternative, you can work with the `itemetter` operator alone.* The idea is to use the collections of elements as a key with the value being a list of element indices this particular collections occurs in. Then, if this list is longer than whatever threshold you chose (the `redundancy` parameter below) we report this particular collection:

```py
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict

# how many times must the collection of elements appear
redundancy = 2
# what are the indices of the collection
target_slots = [1, 2] 

# the example data:
eg_data_2 =  [(0, 'Boby', 'beekeeper'), (1, 'Boby', 'beekeeper'), (2, 'Boby','beekeeper'), (3, 'Boby', 'gardener'), (4, 'Boby', 'gardener'), (5, 'Jack', 'gardener')]


occurences = defaultdict(list)  # this is just convenient, you can use a normal dict as well.
for i, entry in enumerate(eg_data_2):
    occurences[itemgetter(*target_slots)(entry)].append(i)
targets = [k for k,v in occurences.items() if len(v) >=redundancy]
targets
Out[18]: [('Boby', 'beekeeper'), ('Boby', 'gardener')]
```

---

In case you want the elements rather than the repeated entries back, you need to slightly adapt the statement for the `targets` as the `sum(1...` will already consume the group iterator.

Here is how this could look:

```py
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

redundancy, target_slots = 2, (1, 2)

eg_data_2 =  [(0, 'Boby', 'beekeeper'), (1, 'Boby', 'beekeeper'), (2, 'Boby','beekeeper'), (3, 'Boby', 'gardener'), (4, 'Boby', 'gardener'), (5, 'Jack', 'gardener')]

_targets = [(k, [e for e in v]) for k, v in groupby(eg_data_2, itemgetter(*target_slots))]
targets = [tg[1] for tg in _targets if len(tg[1]) >= redundancy]
```

Which will give:

```py
[ins] In [6]: targets                                                           
Out[6]: 
[[(0, 'Boby', 'beekeeper'),
  (1, 'Boby', 'beekeeper'),
  (2, 'Boby', 'beekeeper')],
 [(3, 'Boby', 'gardener'), (4, 'Boby', 'gardener')]]
```

Comment: At the output, I get an element with two values, is it possible to implement this as well, but get everything at once? (1566767108.0, 'Boris Johnson', 'dorety', 'sfp_names', 'HUMAN_NAME', 100, 100, 0, '7931', '08f3', 'Human Name', 'ENTITY', '19fd', 0, 0 )

Comment: @question_mark_77 added a version where you'll get the actual elements back (see end of my reply). Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks. But this is not exactly what I had in mind, but this is just the next thing that I needed

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to get all the tuples from a list of tuples that have a duplicate value for a specific element of the tuple, but want to keep only those groups of duplicates that have a varying value for some other specific element of the tuple?

If so, I'm sorry to say you didn't do a very good job of explaining that and I mention that because getting a clear understanding of a problem, so you can explain it in a few words, also happens to be the best first step to coding something.

Example data:

```py
[('a', 1, 0), ('a', 2, 0), ('b', 1, 0), ('c', 1, 0), ('c', 1, 0)]
```

In this example, assuming you'd be looking at the 1st (index 0) and 2nd (index 1) elements, I would expect you want `[('a', 1, 0), ('a', 2, 0)]` as a result. The tuple with `'b'` isn't included because there is no second and the tuple with `'c'` isn't included because there is a second, but it does not have a different value for the other element.

Second example

```py
('d', 1, 0), ('d', 2, 0), ('d', 2, 1)]
```

Something you don't address is shown here. They should be included, because the first element is the same for all and the second is not, but should all three be included, or just one (at random, or the first) of the tuples that has `2` for the second element? I'm assuming you'd want all of them because they meet your first two criteria.

```py
from itertools import groupby

data = [('a', 1, 0), ('a', 2, 0), ('b', 1, 0), ('c', 1, 0), ('c', 1, 0)]


def my_filter(el1, el2, xs):
    return [e for l in [list(g) for k, g in groupby(xs, lambda x: x[el1])]
            for e in l if len(set([e[el2] for e in l])) > 1]


print(my_filter(0, 1, data))
```